# Error: #include nested too deeply in Dev C++

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation

Given below is my boilerplate/ macros that I use. Whenever I hit compile, compiler of DEV C++11 starts compilation and never completes it. It scans all header files and also shows "Error: #include nested too deeply", but doesn't stop. What can be the fix for this?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<map>
#define int long long
#define MOD 1000000007
#define br break
#define rem 500009
#define PI 3.1415926535
#define INF 1e18 
#define ve vector
#define mp make_pair
#define pb push_back
#define pf push_front
#define ppb pop_back
#define ppf pop_front
#define mxe(v) *max_element(v.begin(),v.end())
#define mne(v) *min_element(v.begin(),v.end())
#define bs binary_search

#define ub upper_bound
#define FAST ios::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);
#define rep(g, i, n) for (int g = i; g < n; g++)
#define rev(g, n, i) for (ll g = n - 1; g >= i; g--)
using namespace std; 
// CODE BEGINS HERE:
void solve()
{



}

 signed main() 
{ 
//#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    //  freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    //  freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
//#endif
    FAST;
    // int t;
    // cin>>t;
    // while(t--)
        solve();
    return 0; 
} 





// sometimes I believe compiler ignores all my comments
```

Comment: if you dont include bits/stdc++.h , does anything change?

Comment: @LukaKostic Nope

Comment: Does the C++ version of `<cmath>` make a difference from the C version of `<math.h>`?  Otherwise, a [mcve] may be useful.

Comment: It looks like you are being sucked into a cargo cult and they are corrupting you into a force for evil. `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` includes the entire C++ Standard Library. That makes the rest of the includes unnecessary. [That said, don't `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). The next couple dozen lines are nothing but pain. Five bucks says your problems all go away if you stop trying to encrypt your code.

Comment: I never would have thought in my life I would see a `signed main`

Comment: Virtually every line in that program is a bad idea. Learn C++ from someone / somewhere other than whom you've been using so far.

Answer (score 3):

Use int main or void main instead of signed main(). Either dont #define int as long long or use void main

Comment: Don't use `void main`. `main` must return `int`. Everything else is fake code spawned from Mordor.